# Organizing rspec 2 tests into 'unit' and 'integration' categories in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec2

How to organize rspec 2 tests into 'unit' (fast) and 'integration' (slow) categories?

- I want to be able to run all unit tests with just `rspec` command, but not the 'integration' tests.
- I want to be able to run only 'integration' tests.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We have groups of the same nature.
We run then one by one both on the local dev boxes and on the CI.

you can simply do

```
bundle exec rake spec:unit
bundle exec rake spec:integration
bundle exec rake spec:api
```

This is what our spec.rake looks like

```
  namespace :spec do
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:unit) do |t|
      t.pattern = Dir['spec/*/**/*_spec.rb'].reject{ |f| f['/api/v1'] || f['/integration'] }
    end

    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:api) do |t|
      t.pattern = "spec/*/{api/v1}*/**/*_spec.rb"
    end

    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:integration) do |t|
      t.pattern = "spec/integration/**/*_spec.rb"
    end
  end
```

Comment: That's great! but..  I added the file to my lib/tasks, but getting errors:
  rake aborted!
  uninitialized constant Rspec

Comment: That's odd, if you have Rspec you should have that simply working for you.

Comment: I had to add rspec-core to Gemfile and add require 'rspec/core/rake_task' to the file.  Strange as I thought having rspec-rails would include those dependencies.

Comment: There is a typo, at least with my setup it should be "RSpec::Core::RakeTask", not "Rspec::..."

Comment: To be explicit, the file should live at `lib/tasks/spec.rake`

Comment: It is recommended by Rspec that you wrap the `load rspec/core/rake_task` line in a begin/rescue block to catch a LoadError. This will allow your rake tasks to be loaded in environments where Rspec is not available

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/rake-task

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it is to tag your RSpec test cases like this:

```
it "should do some integration test", :integration => true do
  # something
end
```

When you execute your test cases use this:

```
rspec . --tag integration
```

This will execute all the test cases with the tag `:integration => true`. For more refer to this [page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option).

Comment: Thank you. And is there a way to exclude these 'integration' cases when running `rspec` command without arguments?

Comment: rspec . --tag ~integration. If you are using zsh then it is a slightly different: rspec . --tag "~integeration"

Comment: @Evgenii: You can also put `--tag "~integration"` in your project **.rpsec** file.  This is my preferred approach.  Of course it is overridden by options you might specify explicitly on the command-line, so you still have complete flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I had to configure my `unit` and `feature` tests as follows:

```
require 'rspec/rails'

namespace :spec do
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:unit) do |t|
    t.pattern = Dir['spec/*/**/*_spec.rb'].reject{ |f| f['/features'] }
  end

  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:feature) do |t|
    t.pattern = "spec/features/**/*_spec.rb"
  end
end
```

Had to add `require 'rspec/rails'` and change `Rspec` to `RSpec` in the answer given by @KensoDev.

Comment: Why not store your unit tests in a separate directory (e.g. `spec/unit`), and use a less-complicated pattern (e.g. `spec/unit/**/*_spec.rb`)?

Answer (score 0):

Notice at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails, they are telling you to place the gem under "group :development, :test" like so,

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end
```

but if you place this only under :test group **only**,

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end
```

then you'll get the above error.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `.rspec` file to configure patterns instead of using `rake` because it's tricky to pass flags to RSpec when using rake.

You can read environment variables in your `.rspec` file:

```
<%= if ENV['TEST'] == 'integration' %>
--pattern spec/integration/**/*_spec.rb
<% else %>
<% ENV['TEST'] = 'unit' %>
--pattern spec/unit/**/*_spec.rb
<% end %>
```

Then you can run `TEST=integration rspec` to run integration tests or just `rspec` to run unit tests. The advantage of this approach is that you can still pass flags to it like:

`TEST=integration rspec -t login -f doc`